# What does big data have to do with cloud computing?

Tags: bigdata, cloud

What does big data have to do with cloud computing?
I have try to explain the relation between big data and cloud computing.

Answer (score 0):

They overlap. One is not dependent on the other. Cloud computing enables companies to rent infrastructure over time rather than pay up-front for computers and maintain it over time.

In general, cloud vendors allow you to rent out large amounts of server pools and build networks of servers (clusters).

You can pay for servers with large storage drives and install software like Hadoop FileSystem (HDFS), Ceph, GlusterFS, etc. These softwares will make a single "shared filesystem". The more servers you combine together into this filesystem, the more data you can store.

Now, that's just storage. Hopefully, these servers also have some reasonable amount of memory and CPU processing. Other technology such as YARN (with Hadoop), Apache Mesos, Kubernetes/Docker allow you to create resource pools to deploy distributed applications that spread over all those servers and read data that's stored in all those other machines.

---

The above is mostly **block storage**, though. The alternative, cheaper alternative is **object storage** such as Amazon S3, which is a Hadoop Compatible filesystem. There are other object storage solutions, but people use this as it's more highly available (via replication) and can be secured easier with access keys and policies

Answer (score 0):

Big data and Cloud Computing are one of the most used technologies in today’s Information Technology world. With these two technologies, business, education, healthcare, research & development, etc are growing rapidly and will provide various advantages to expand their areas with tricks and techniques.
In cloud computing, we can store and retrieve the data from anywhere at any time. Whereas, big data is the large set of data which will process to extract the necessary information.

A customer can shift to Cloud Computing when they need rapid deployment and scaling of the applications. The application deals with highly sensitive data and requires strict compliance one should keep things on the cloud. Whereas, we can use Big Data for traditional methods and here frameworks are ineffective. Big data is not replacement for relational database system and big data solve specific problem statement related to large data sets and most of the large data sets do not deal with small data.

Big Data Technology is Hadoop, MapReduce, and HDFS. while Cloud Computing includes three types which are: public, private, hybrid and community cloud. 
Cloud computing provides enterprises a cost-effective & flexible way to access a vast volume of information we call the Big Data. Because of Big Data and cloud computing, it is now much easier to start an IT company than ever before. When the combination of big data and cloud computing was first initiated, it opened the road to endless possibilities. Various fields have seen many drastic changes that were made possible by this combination. It changed the decision-making process for companies and gave a huge advantage to analysts, who could base their results on concrete data.